# Avoid tight coupling when configuring a service from a backend

Tags: microservices, coupling

I have multiple apps (**app 1**, ..., **app n**), that don't know each other but use the same services. At the same time, there is a single application to configure the services (let's call it **backend**).

One service in particular simply stores content, that we have created using an editor and provides it to the applications through the api-gateway. The editor uses the same renderer as the applications use in order to ensure the content will be displayed as desired. This renderer (**ContentRenderer**) has knowledge about the **ContentModel**.

The service, however uses a validator (**ContentValidator**) when receiving the content from the backend in order to ensure it's fits the **ContentModel**. Now here I feel that this service is rather a part of a distributed monolith because of the shared **ContentModel**.

To visualize this I have created a simple (non-UML) overview:

[image]

How can I avoid this coupling but ensure

- the editors still work with the same renderer as the apps will use and
- the content is still validated with the appropriate model

I first had the idea to add a ContentModel designer to the backend, which allows to define the model, injecting it to validator and renderer but I have the strange feeling that I just move the coupling to the runtime. Do I miss something here? Is this the wrong approach for this situation?

Comment: seems to me you dont have any tight coupling you cant get around with an interface or two

Comment: I'm also not sure what is your concern. Is `ContentModel` somehow coupled with your app 1, ... appn ?

Comment: Currently the services and the apps are all nodejs apps. The `ContentModel` is currently a shared library, loaded by `ContentRenderer`(itself a lib, loaded by the apps and the backend) and `content` to be used with the `ContentValidator`. I am thinking of rewriting the `content` service in another language. At this point I get a bad feeling, because I will end up with two `ContentModel` (one in each language) that I have to keep in sync and this makes me wonder if I ran into a coupling problem. This is my first approach to such a setup.